# Java 8 stream and foreach loop

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Which is faster stream or for each loop and why? which should be used in which scenario?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ran {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Get and shuffle the list of arguments
        List<String> argList = Arrays.asList(args);
        Collections.shuffle(argList);

        // Print out the elements using JDK 8 Streams
        argList.stream()
        .forEach(e->System.out.format("%s ",e));

        // Print out the elements using for-each
        for (String arg: argList) {
            System.out.format("%s ", arg);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: The stream is likely slower.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect the stream version to be slighter slower as it involves more work but by what margin this is you'll really need to measure.

Unless performance is *really* *really* important to you I wouldn't worry about it but instead go with the approach that most expresses your needs and that you find most readable.

FYI,  `argList.stream().forEach(...)` can be simplied to   `argList.forEach(...)`